# Minecraft server puts files in desktop

Tags: shell, minecraft

I'm trying to run 2 minecraft servers on a schedule. when I try to start the server, it puts the files used by the servers in my desktop. this doesn't work because the files from the other server would interfere. Please help.

Before, I had 2 files in each of the servers' respective folders, but when i ran them from the desktop, they would give me this error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile [file.jar]

Minecraft 1.14.4 and 1.13.2 servers

> openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~19.04.1-b10)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

File in server folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xmx2G -Xms1G -jar server.jar

$SHELL
```

Master run file:

```
#!/bin/sh


for a in 3 4 5 6 7
do
    if [ $((a % 2))==1 ]; then
        cp -avr SurvivalServer/World SurvivalServer/Backup
        java -Xmx2G -Xms1G -jar "home/steve/Desktop/SurvivalServer/server.jar"
        sleep 12h
        kill 2134
    else
        cp -avr CreativeServer/ReEnforcers CreativeServer/Backup
        java -Xms2G -Xmx1G -jar "home/steve/Desktop/CreativeServer/server.jar"
        sleep 12h
        kill 2042
    fi
    sleep 12h   
done
```

I thought it would flip the servers on and off every 12 hours, but instead it gives me this error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile home/steve/Desktop/SurvivalServer/server.jar

(server.jar is the server start file.)

Answer (score 0):

That error is one of two things, you should check both of these:

1. Permissions in that directory. Ensure that the directory the program is located in is readable/writable with your current script.
2. Ensure you are spelling the name of the file correctly, capitalization matters!

Comment: actually, I made all permissions read/write and it still puts files in the desktop or some other root folder.